# Applying attributes to a video

Tags: html, css

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, san-serif;
}

header {
  background: #3E474F;
  box-shadow: 0 .5em 1em #111;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
}

header label {
  color: #788188;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 4.25em;
  font-size: .677em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

header label:hover {
  background: #2E353B;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 8em 1em 0;
  background-color: #120103;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide-one {
  background-image: url('jupiter.jpg');
}

.slide-two {
  background-image: url('neptune.jpg');
}

.slide-three {
  background-image: url('mars.jpg');
}

.slide-four {
  background-image: url('moon.jpg');
}

[id^="slide"]:checked+.slide {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

video {
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pure CSS Horizontal Slider</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=" 1 "/>
  <link rel="stylesheet " type="text/css " href="main1.css " />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap ">
    <header>
      <label for="slide-1-trigger ">Slide One</label>
      <label for="slide-2-trigger ">Slide Two</label>
      <label for="slide-3-trigger ">Slide Three</label>
      <label for="slide-4-trigger ">Slide Four</label>
    </header>
    <input id="slide-1-trigger " type="radio " name="slides " checked/>
    <section class="slide slide-one ">
      <h1>Headline One</h1>
      <video width="250 " height="170 " controls>
   <source src="jupitergif.webm " type="video/webm ">
   </source>
   </video>
    </section>
    <input id="slide-2-trigger " type="radio " name="slides " />
    <section class="slide slide-two ">
      <h1>Headline Two</h1>
    </section>
    <input id="slide-3-trigger " type="radio " name="slides " />
    <section class="slide slide-three ">
      <h1>Headline Three</h1>
    </section>
    <input id="slide-4-trigger " type="radio " name="slides " />
    <section class="slide slide-four ">
      <h1>Headline Four</h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> I am having trouble styling the video so that it is in the bottom right corner of the page. Also, how can I make the video autoplay on a loop? Also, how can I get rid of any play/maximize icons on the video? The video is in section class slide slide-one. Much appreciated.

Comment: Remove 'controls' from your video tag. Add 'loop' to loop the video. Also, I don't see a video loading on your snippet.

Comment: @cosmoonot The video is not loading in the snippet because it is a local file. Thanks for telling me to remove controls. Adding loop did not work. Also how can I get the video in the bottom right corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `autoplay` and `loop` attributes to `<video>` and remove `controls`. The `<source>` void element which doesn't have an end tag **<del></source></del>**

> ```
> <video width="250" height="170" autoplay loop>
> ```

For placing the video in the bottom right corner use:

> ```
>  video {
>     z-index: 10000;
>     position:fixed;
>     bottom:0;
>     right:0;
>   }
> ```

BTW keep your format consistent all of the right quotes have a space before them, remove those spaces.

**SNIPPET**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, san-serif;
}

header {
  background: #3E474F;
  box-shadow: 0 .5em 1em #111;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
}

header label {
  color: #788188;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 4.25em;
  font-size: .677em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

header label:hover {
  background: #2E353B;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 8em 1em 0;
  background-color: #120103;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide-one {
  background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/628266121313947648/Zk_c8qnD.jpg');
}

.slide-two {
  background-image: url('https://dperkins.org/gal/2014/thumb/2014-10-06.18.Neptune.jpg');
}

.slide-three {
  background-image: url('https://at-cdn-s01.audiotool.com/2011/10/04/documents/FHCjD1iBHjEiCESy8ubgBopVfNr/0/cover256x256-dd1bb728ff564ec69ededd71b2ba4ada.jpg');
}

.slide-four {
  background-image: url('https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/82/42/9a/82429a1b-a489-d421-5ec2-cb38613b54f4/source/256x256bb.jpg');
}

[id^="slide"]:checked+.slide {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

video {
  z-index: 10000;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pure CSS Horizontal Slider</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <header>
      <label for="slide-1-trigger">Slide One</label>
      <label for="slide-2-trigger">Slide Two</label>
      <label for="slide-3-trigger">Slide Three</label>
      <label for="slide-4-trigger">Slide Four</label>
    </header>

    <input id="slide-1-trigger" type="radio" name="slides" checked/>
    <section class="slide slide-one">
      <h1>Headline One</h1>
      <video width="250" height="170" autoplay loop>
   <source src="http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4" type="video/webm">
   </video>
    </section>

    <input id="slide-2-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
    <section class="slide slide-two">
      <h1>Headline Two</h1>
    </section>

    <input id="slide-3-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
    <section class="slide slide-three">
      <h1>Headline Three</h1>
    </section>

    <input id="slide-4-trigger" type="radio" name="slides">
    <section class="slide slide-four">
      <h1>Headline Four</h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```